# what does it mean by the state "Indeterminate"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

when It comes to checkboxes there is a third state called "Indeterminate", what does it mean?

what other controls have this "Indeterminate" state?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`CheckBox.CheckState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Indeterminate
>
> - The CheckBox displays a check mark and is **shaded**.
> - The control appears flat.

Here a nice virtualization of what is exactly mean..

[image]

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/mGg85/2/)</kbd> with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless copy and paste from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox):

> Some applications use checkboxes that allow an indeterminate state in
>   addition to the two provided by a normal checkbox. This third state is
>   shown as a square or dash in the checkbox, and indicates that its
>   state is neither checked nor unchecked. This is most often used when
>   the checkbox is tied to a collection of items in mixed states. The
>   indeterminate state cannot usually be selected by the user, and
>   switches to a checked state when activated.
>
> For example, a checkbox presented to select files to send via FTP
>   might use a tree view so that files can be selected one at a time, or
>   by folder. If only some of the files in a folder are selected, then
>   the checkbox for that folder would be indeterminate. Clicking on this
>   indeterminate checkbox would select all or, less commonly, none of the
>   contained files. Continuing to click on the checkbox would alternate
>   between checked (all sub-directories and files selected) and unchecked
>   (no sub-directories or files selected).
>
> Some tri-state checkbox implementations allow the user to toggle among
>   all states, including the indeterminate state, by remembering the
>   mixed state of the items in the collection. This serves as an undo
>   feature.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a CheckBox, indeterminate could be used to indicate a "we don't know yet" kind of answer when a true/false situation is present.

Indeterminate can also be used in cases where multiple selection is involved and some items in the list are true, but others false.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On binding checkbox if property value is null than checkbox show indetermine state.